# ASP.NET Core MVC : changing view based on user inputted value

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, layout, view, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm writing an ASP.NET Core MVC application and I have three views `_AdminLayout`, `_DeactivatedAdminLayout` and `_Layout`.

Basically the current code checks if the user is an admin and if they are their is a value currently stored in `viewAdmin` that dictates if the user is seeing `_AdminLayout` or `_DeactivatedAdminLayout`.

This is what my `_ViewStart` looks like now:

```
@{
    List<string> authorizedUsers = new List<string>();
    bool viewAdmin = false;

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("Admin_Users.txt"))
    {
        String line;

        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            authorizedUsers.Add(line);
        }
    }

    if (authorizedUsers.Contains(User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "preferred_username").Value) && viewAdmin== true)
    {
        Layout = "_AdminLayout";
    }
    else if (authorizedUsers.Contains(User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "preferred_username").Value) && viewAdmin == false)
    {
        Layout = "_DeactivatedAdminLayout";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "_Layout";
    }
}
```

What I want is a way to let the user change the viewAdmin value. I have buttons in `_AdminLayout` and `_DeactivatedAdminLayout` and I want it so that when the user clicks on a the button the ensuing methods changes the `viewAdmin` value but I'm not sure how to do this

I've looked online but I can only find information about global variables that wont be changed but not how to change the type of layout within the layout

EDIT: I FIGURED IT OUT!

Ok so I wanted the layout to change on the button click to change between the admin layout and deactivated admin layout. So what I did is I added

```
@{
    Layout = "_AdminLayout";
}
```

To all of the admin pages, which changes the layout in them to the admin page while all the non admin pages retain the _deactivatedAdminLayout Then in _adminLayout I have a button

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-radius:10px; margin-right:20px;">
   Normal View
</a>
```

and in _deactivatedAdminLayout I have the button

```
<a asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="FindProfileAdmin" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-radius:10px; margin-right:20px;">
     Admin View
</a>
```

This way when they click the button they are sent to either the admin home page or the regular home page and the layout I want is displayed.

Comment: viewAdmin won't be stored on server,it won't exists once the view was rendered to html,next time you send another request,viewAdmin would be innitialized with false